# Make div fixed height by percent

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a div with 100% width of parent and now i want it to be 10% height of parent (no mater how long the content is).

I set `height: 10%` but it still didn't solve my problem.

Here is my css:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #008CDA;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All his parent must have height: 100%.

usually it looks like this:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color:grey;
}
.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  background-color:yellow;
}
.your_div {
  height: 10%;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="your_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This fixed my problem, i forgot the html height! Thank you so much!

Comment: @tuankhoa1996 you welcome

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick JSfiddle showing a parent-child layed out as you describe:
https://jsfiddle.net/k0jur7yf/

```
{.child {
  height:10%;
  width:100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Could you show us a snippet of your code if this doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: Yes! i want it exact to be like that but mine is depend on the long of the content inside it :(. If there is no content in the div, it's blank :(

Comment: You can avoid displaying the part of the content outside your div using `overflow: hidden` in your child class (https://jsfiddle.net/k0jur7yf/1/), does this help?

Comment: the problem fixed by set html height to 100%. I only set the body. Thank you so much for response! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check it, first make a div and its class parent.
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XfjP.jpg)
Added the following class in your Css file or in head.
.parent {height:10%; width:100%;}

Answer (score 0):

In div If you use width and height style in % then it will adjust according to content but when you use style in px then it will take according to size of the width and height.
example:

```
<div style="width:100%;height:10%;border: 3px solid red">FOr example</div>

<div style="width:100px;height:10px:border:3px solid red">
```